# how to send 10 items from an array in each request until the array is empty

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, single-page-application

I have an array of cards each card is an object. The client want to upload all the cards for example 100 cards, and when he submit he want each 10 cards to be sent in separate http request. How to achieve  that ?

This is my component for now. I have managed to take 10 cards from an array and log them then delete them from the array .

```
<template>
  <v-data-table
    :search="search"
    :headers="headers"
    :items="getCards"
    sort-by="calories"
    class="elevation-1"
  >
    <template v-slot:top>
      <v-toolbar flat color="white">
        <v-text-field v-model="search" label="Search" single-line hide-details></v-text-field>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="500px">
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
            <v-btn color="primary" dark class="mb-2" v-on="on">Add cards</v-btn>
          </template>
          <v-card>
            <v-card-title>
              <span class="headline">Add cards</span>
            </v-card-title>
            <v-card-text>
              <v-container grid-list-md>
                <v-layout wrap>
                  <v-flex xs12 sm6 md4>
                    <v-select v-model="cardsPostData.groupId" :items="groups" label="Group"></v-select>
                  </v-flex>
                  <v-flex xs12 sm6 md4>
                    <v-select v-model="cardsPostData.type" :items="types" label="Type"></v-select>
                  </v-flex>
                  <v-flex xs12 sm6 md4>
                    <v-select
                      v-model="cardsPostData.cardInfoName"
                      :items="infonames"
                      label="Card info name"
                    ></v-select>
                  </v-flex>
                  <v-flex xs12 sm6 md12>
                    <v-textarea hint="display cards here" v-model="cardsString" label="Cards"></v-textarea>
                  </v-flex>
                  <v-flex xs12 sm6 md4></v-flex>
                </v-layout>
              </v-container>
            </v-card-text>

            <v-card-actions>
              <v-spacer></v-spacer>
              <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="close">Cancel</v-btn>
              <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="save">Save</v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-card>
        </v-dialog>
      </v-toolbar>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:item.action="{ item }">
      <v-icon small @click="deleteItem(item)">mdi-delete</v-icon>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:no-data>
      <v-btn color="primary" @click="initialize">Reset</v-btn>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  data: () => ({
    dialog: false,
    search: "",
    headers: [
      {
        text: "Name",
        align: "left",
        sortable: false,
        value: "name"
      },
      { text: "Username", value: "username" },
      { text: "Password", value: "phone" },
      { text: "Debt", value: "email" },
      { text: "Max Debt", value: "website" },
      { text: "Actions", value: "action", sortable: false }
    ],
    groups: ["group1", "group2", "group3", "group4"],
    types: ["Earthlink", "others"],
    infonames: ["st", "mt"],
    cardsString: "",

    getCards: [],
    allProcessedCards: [],
    theChosenTenCards: [],

    cardsPostData: {
      groupId: "",
      type: "",
      cardInfoName: "",
      cards: []
    }
  }),

  computed: {
    //
  },

  watch: {
    dialog(val) {
      val || this.close();
    }
  },

  created() {
    this.initialize();
  },

  methods: {
    initialize() {
      axios
        .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
        .then(response => (this.getCards = response.data));
    },

    cardsRefactoring() {
      const cardsarry = this.cardsString.split("\n");
      if (this.cardsPostData.type == "Earthlink") {
        for (let i = 0; i < cardsarry.length; i++) {
          const card = cardsarry[i];
          const carditems = card.split(",");
          const obj = {
            serial: carditems[0],
            username: carditems[1],
            password: carditems[2]
          };
          this.allProcessedCards.push(obj);
        }
      } else {
        for (let i = 0; i < cardsarry.length; i++) {
          const card = cardsarry[i];
          const carditems = card.split(",");
          const obj = {
            serial: carditems[0]
          };
          this.allProcessedCards.push(obj);
        }
      }
    },

    snedingProcess() {
      for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        this.theChosenTenCards.push(this.allProcessedCards[i]);
      }

    },
    deleteSentCards(){
        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        this.allProcessedCards.splice(this.theChosenTenCards[i],1);
      }
    },

    deleteItem(item) {
      const index = this.getCards.indexOf(item);
      confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?") &&
        //we send the deleted item in delete request insted
        this.getCards.splice(index, 1);
    },

    close() {
      this.dialog = false;
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, this.defaultItem);
        this.editedIndex = -1;
      }, 300);
    },

    save() {
      this.cardsRefactoring();
      this.snedingProcess();
      this.deleteSentCards();
      this.close();
      console.log("chosen ten:",this.theChosenTenCards);
      console.log("all cards:",this.allProcessedCards);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

My input in the text-area :

```
serial1,username,password
serial2,username,password
serial3,username,password
serial4,username,password
serial5,username,password
serial6,username,password
serial7,username,password
serial8,username,password
serial9,username,password
serial10,username,password
serial11,username,password
serial12,username,password
serial13,username,password
serial14,username,password
serial15,username,password
```

My output will be :

```
array of 10 items 

array of the rest 5 items
```

Comment: I guess you will love `lodash.chunk`.

See [lodash#chunk](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#chunk)

Comment: sending as in async requests. Split the array in batch of 10 and apply promise.all on all batches

Comment: lodash seems promising , thank you guys will test it out

Comment: I would remove most of the code you've posted and narrow down your case, you just want to partion the array to send request with each 10 items, if doesn't matter that you use Vue.js You can safely remove all html and leave single function with your array, for loop and axios request.

Comment: yeah sorry for not doing that in the first place :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [lodash.chunk](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#chunk) it does great job by splitting my cards array into small chunks each chunk is 10 cards , and when the last chunk is 4 cards or something lower than 10 it will count it as chunk also ,, worked for me -- thanks to [Long Nguyen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11938709/long-nguyen) for pointing me out to lodash

and here is the code :

```
 cardsRefactoring() {
      const cardsarry = this.cardsString.split("\n");
      if (this.cardsPostData.type == "Earthlink") {
        for (let i = 0; i < cardsarry.length; i++) {
          const card = cardsarry[i];
          const carditems = card.split(",");
          const obj = {
            serial: carditems[0],
            username: carditems[1],
            password: carditems[2]
          };
          this.allProcessedCards.push(obj);
        }
      } else {
        for (let i = 0; i < cardsarry.length; i++) {
          const card = cardsarry[i];
          const carditems = card.split(",");
          const obj = {
            serial: carditems[0]
          };
          this.allProcessedCards.push(obj);
        }
      }
      const chunkedCards = _.chunk(this.allProcessedCards, 10)
      for(let i=0 ;i < chunkedCards.length; i++){
        const chunk = chunkedCards[i];
         for(let i = 0; i< chunk.length; i++){
          this.cardsPostData.cards.push(chunk[i])
        } 
        console.log("chuncked ten", this.cardsPostData.cards);

        this.cardsPostData.cards = []
      } 
    },
```